# How do I broadcast an event from a Laravel based server to .net C# based client?

Tags: c#, laravel, laravel-5, redis

I am developing a Laravel REST API based server with MySQL DB and client is in .net C#. I want to know how to broadcast event from Laravel to C# client. I know one option is to use Pusher but its free version is limited.

I want to know if we can use Redis, if yes then how to use it in C# (.net) client to get the broadcasted message/event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use concept of [webhooks](https://codeburst.io/what-are-webhooks-b04ec2bf9ca2). For example : If an activity X occurs at the server end, it will send a post request to the C# web client on a pre-specified url. Then the client can handle that post request and perform actions on it's own.

Now, if you are looking for a very quick open-source realtime event broadcasting, you can check out apache [kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) or [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) etc.